# Jquery mobile, google maps and phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

i have been using google maps in jquery mobile and they are working well but when i convert my app in phonegap google maps stops working. i am using phonegap 1.4.1

Comment: not enough information, look in the logs for errors

Comment: no way to debug using this info.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a bit more on that in order to understand your issue?
It might all be related to the whitelisting of source domains.
Could it be you need to [incorporate](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/40796976) the domains of google in your plist file?
You can find those whitelisted domains in ***[your_app]*/Supporting files/*[your_app]*.plist**

I had to include in the External Hosts section:

- *.gstatic.com
- *.googleapis.com
- *.google.com